# C# FreePIE YEI Space Sensor 3 - Stream Data

Tags: c#, dll, marshalling

I am having a problem using the ThreeSpace_API.dll whilst trying to add support for the sensor to freePIE. Using the polling method is working fine. However I am having an issue with streaming.

Using VS 2012 this works absolutely fine. However after building and trying to run through the executable it crashes with the following error:

```
Application: FreePIE.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
at FreePIE.Core.Plugins.Yei3Space.Api.tss_getLastStreamData(Int32, FreePIE.Core.Plugins.Yei3Space.TssStreamPacket ByRef, Int32)
at FreePIE.Core.Plugins.Yei3Space.Api.UpdateQuaternion(Int32,   FreePIE.Core.Plugins.SensorFusion.Quaternion)
at FreePIE.Core.Plugins.Yei3SpaceGlobalHolder.Update()
```

It is called in the following way:

```
//DLL Call to ThreeSpace_API.dll
[DllImport("ThreeSpace_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern TssError tss_getLastStreamData(int id, out TssStreamPacket packet, int size);

//Stream Packet Struct
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct TssStreamPacket
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public float[] quat;        
}

// Starts streaming asynchronous data
public static void StartStreamingU(int device_id)
{
    int count;
    byte[] stream_slots = new byte[8];
    stream_slots[0] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_GET_TARED_ORIENTATION_AS_QUATERNION;
    stream_slots[1] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[2] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[3] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[4] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[5] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[6] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;
    stream_slots[7] = (byte)TssStreaming.TSS_NULL;

    count=0;
    if( !is_streaming )
    {
        while( count < 3 )
        {
            if( tss_setStreamingTiming(device_id,0,-1,1500000) == 0 )
            {
                if( tss_setStreamingSlots(device_id,stream_slots) == 0 )
                {
                    if( tss_startStreaming(device_id) == 0 )
                    {
                        is_streaming=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            count++;
        }
    }    
}

public static TssError UpdateQuaternion(int deviceId, Quaternion quaternion)
{
    uint timestamp;
    float[] fltQuat = new float[4];
    TssStreamPacket packet = new TssStreamPacket();            
    TssError error = TssError.TSS_NO_ERROR;            
    if(is_streaming)
    {
        try
        {
            error = tss_getLastStreamData(deviceId, out packet, 16);
            fltQuat[0] = packet.quat[0];
            fltQuat[1] = packet.quat[1];
            fltQuat[2] = packet.quat[2];
            fltQuat[3] = packet.quat[3];                                        
        }
        catch (System.AccessViolationException e)
        {
            return TssError.TSS_ERROR_READ;
        }
    }
}
```

The annoying thing is that it works fine through debugger so there is not much I can do to test this. I have tried various alternatives to marshalling the data back. Interestingly doing this via a normal float array seems to block the CPU.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Shouldnt size be 16? Also can you please supply the C h file?

Comment: H-file http://pastebin.com/7revudK6

Comment: Thanks for adding header file - sorry I didnt see comment earlier but thought would e-mail me when a comment added. For the full C h file and examples the YEI latest API is here:http://forum.yeitechnology.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=27

Comment: There is also a good example looking at the UDK integration. Its C++ but useful to see sizes of elements etc 
http://www.yeitechnology.com/head-tracking-yei-3-space-sensor-udk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapper is missing the timestamp parameter.

This is the declaration from yei_threespace_api.

```
TSS_EXPORT TSS_Error tss_getLastStreamData(TSS_Device_Id device, char * output_data, unsigned int output_data_len, unsigned int * timestamp);
```

Tested and now working fine!